# Quais as vantagens e desvantagens de utilizar BaaS

Tags: services, back-end, baas

Ontem presenciei uma palestra onde foi apresentando algumas coisas sobre `BaaS(Backend as a Service)`. Após isso surgiram algumas dúvidas:

- Seguindo esse modelo a necessidade de se criar um `back-end` por
  completo é eliminada levando o projeto a ser concluído mais rápido,
  mas em contra partida o que se perde com isso?
- Quais as vantagens e desvantagens do modelo comparado ao modelo tradicional onde desenvolvemos todo o `back-end`? O fato de não conhecer a estrutura do serviço BaaS pode influenciar em algo?

Comment: Não sei responder com precisão, mas conheço a mentalidade da indústria. Isso parece ter sido criado para resolver um problema próprio, criar um produto novo, mais que resolver um problema, que até resolve um pouco, senão ninguém compraria. Certamente começou pra evitar pirataria. Juntar massa de dados é um "ótimo" efeito colateral. Vender algo que com valor agregado (valor pode ser benefício ou pode ser só custo mesmo). A pergunta é pertinente para levantar o ganho de se fazer isso e expor os problemas. Espero que tenha boas respostas. Eu só poderia dar uma meia-boca.

Comment: Acabei de perceber uma coisa. Vantagem e desvantagem em relação a que? À nada? Aí tem um monte de vantagem, a maioria genérica para comprar qualquer coisa pronta, não importa como entrega. Se comparar esse modelo com um modelo tradicional de biblioteca, aí as vantagens passam ser bem menores e as desvantagens aumentam bem. Percebi isso porque a resposta dada compara com nada, ou seja, fazer tudo na mão. Não considero uma comparação justa de modelos. E a resposta não está errada porque a pergunta não específica. De uma certa forma é ampla.

Comment: @bigown Realmente, vou tentar melhorar mais a pergunta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essa sua dúvida se assemelha com a dúvida entre criar um site do zero ou usar um WordPress, acho que as vantagens e desvantagem são parecidos.
Na minha experiencia utilizando uma BaaS (Firebase) são:

Vantagens:

1. Você não precisa demandar tempo/dinheiro para criar um back-end
2. Os custos de hospedagem do seu back-end na nuvem costumam ser
   mais caros que o custo do BaaS
3. O seu back-end é atualizado para
   uma melhor segurança e otimização sem a necessidade de você fazer
   nada
4. Você tem uma boa integração entre os serviços
5. Outros serviços como test de bugs também são oferecidos por estes sistemas
6. Se os grandes players do mercado estão criando este tipo de serviço é porque agrega valor e há mercado

Desvantagem:

1. Você depende apenas das funcionalidades que o BaaS te fornece
2. Você deve confiar seus dados a empresa fornecedora do serviço
3. Você está confiando no sistema de segurança do serviço
4. Algumas funções podem ser limitadas para a sua aplicação
5. Você pode ser expulso do serviço por algum motivo e perder o acesso
6. Você depende desta empresa, se ela fechar você terá que migrar para
   outra prestadora de serviço

Pode parecer que existem muitas desvantagens, mas acredito que somente uma aplicação muito específica não se encaixe no uso de um BaaS, utilizo o Firebase e ele supre todas as minhas necessidades além de ter uma versão gratuita muito generosa.