# O que é um Backend as a Service (BaaS)?

Tags: terminologia, services, middleware, baas

Gostaria de uma explicação do que é um BaaS que suprisse algumas dúvidas:

- O que é BaaS?
- Em geral, são uma API e/ou *framework* e/ou biblioteca? Por que?
- Quais são os principais? Quais as vantagens e desvantagens entre eles?
- Quais as principais tecnologias por trás deles?

Comment: Relacionada https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/153205/quais-as-vantagens-e-desvantagens-de-utilizar-baas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Um [BaaS](http://martinfowler.com/articles/serverless.html) pode ser visto como **uma ponte** conectando o **backend** e o **frontend** de uma aplicação. Os **BaaS** auxiliam os desenvolvedores a acelerar a criação de aplicações web e mobile e simplificam a criação de **APIs**. Em vez de codificar o backend inteiro, o desenvolvedor usa o **BaaS** para criar as **APIs** e conectá-las às aplicações.

**Por que utilizar um BaaS?**

> **Backend-as-a-service (BaaS)** é um serviço de computação em nuvem que serve como middleware. O mesmo fornece aos desenvolvedores uma
>   forma para conectar suas aplicações mobile e web a serviços na nuvem a
>   partir de **APIs** e **SDKs**.
>
> O **BaaS** possibilita aos desenvolvedores mobile e web a abstrair
>   completamente a infraestrutura do lado do servidor **(server side infrastructure)**. Os desenvolvedores podem montar os blocos de
>   construção necessários e apenas escrever o código que os conecta. Isso
>   permite que os desenvolvedores se concentrem na experiência dousuário
>   **(Front end U/X)** em vez de lidar com a infraestrutura e codificação do
>   backend.
>
> Aplicações web e mobile demandam um conjunto de características
>   análogas e muitas atividades repetitivas. Por exemplo, a criação de
>   uma página de Log In e Log Out está presente em quase todos os sites e
>   faz bastante sentido automatizar sua criação. Há muitos outros
>   exemplos de atividades repetitivas comuns em aplicações, como
>   notificação por e-mail, integração com redes sociais e notificações
>   Push. Em geral, esses serviços apresentam sua própria API e precisam
>   ser incorporados separadamente à aplicação. A criação demanda muito
>   tempo e esforço e pode ser automatizada com a utilização de um **BaaS**.
>
> **Um dos principais objetivos** do **BaaS** é automatizar atividades
>   repetitivas e evitar utilizar desenvolvedores para realizar tarefas de
>   baixo valor agregado. Desta forma, as horas alocadas para o
>   desenvolvimento de um projeto de software ficam restritas às tarefas
>   complexas e de alto valor agregado e que não podem ser automatizadas.
>   O custo total do desenvolvimento de um backend pode ser reduzido em
>   até 80% a partir da utilização de um BaaS e o tempo de desenvolvimento
>   do backend também pode ser minimizado.
>
> **O tempo de aprendizado para utilização** de um **BaaS** é relativamente
>   pequeno, permitindo que para sistemas de menor escala um desenvolvedor Frontend ou Mobile construa um projeto inteiro de software **(frontend + backend)** sozinho. Para projetos maiores, o desenvolvedor do **backend**
>   pode focar seus esforços em atividades de alto valor agregado.

**Principais empresas do mercado BaaS**

> Até o inicio de 2016 o maior representante do mercado de **BaaS** era
>   o [Parse.com](http://Parse.com). A empresa, que faz parte do Facebook, tem mais de um
>   milhão de aplicativos instalados em sua plataforma, e mais de 600 mil
>   usuários. O Parse foi adquirido pelo Facebook em 2013, mas no início
>   de 2016 a rede social decidiu finalizar as operações da empresa. Em
>   2017 a plataforma será descontinuada. Com isto, milhões de aplicações
>   terão que buscar alternativas para migração. Algumas opções de BaaS
>   são mostradas abaixo:
>
> - **[Back4app](http://www.back4app.com)** - Empresa criada no Brasil que auxilia
>     desenvolvedores e empresas a migrar aplicações do Parse. Suporta
>     aplicações web, mobile e IoT e é Open Source.
> - **[Firebase](http://www.firebase.com)** - Permite o armazenamento de dados, autenticação de usuário, hospedagem estática, e muito mais.
> - **AWS Móvel Hub** - este é um substituto Parse direta que recentemente saiu pela AWS. Embora este está em Beta, AWS é uma plataforma bem respeitado que suporta muitos grandes empresas como Netflix e Yelp. AWS Móvel Hub - desenvolver, testar e Lançamento Mobile Apps
> - **[BackAnd](http://www.backand.com)** - Uma plataforma que permite a criação de uma infra-estrutura pronta AngularJS para a sua aplicação.
> - **[RapidAPI](http://www.rapidapi.com)** - Uma plataforma de back-end que permite a gravação de dados e integração de APIs.
> - **[Stamplay](http://www.stamplay.com)** - Permite a construção de aplicativos em seu navegador sem codificação usando APIs como blocos.
>
> Veja uma lista no Quora com as [principais alternativas ao Parse](https://www.quora.com/What-alternatives-exist-to-Parse-now-that-it-is-shutting-down).

**Mercado**

> Conforme mostrado nos sites da Technavio e Marketsandmarkets, o
>   mercado de BaaS terá taxa de crescimento superior a 80% ao ano e
>   atingirá 28 bilhões de dólares em 2020, ou seja, será aproximadamente
>   10 vezes maior que o atual no final da década.
>
> O crescimento será motivado pelas economias orientadas a aplicativos
>   em todo mundo e a indispensabilidade de aplicativos móveis na criação
>   de valor econômico. Os aplicativos também apresentam um impacto
>   bastante grande nas indústrias como um todo e trazem mudanças
>   disruptivas em negócios e processos. O conceito de mobilidade
>   empresarial gira em torno de aplicativos e virtualmente todas as
>   organizações estão investindo em aplicações mobile para aumentar a
>   mobilidade.
>
> Em 2020 existirão cerca de 20 milhões de desenvolvedores no mundo e
>   este se tornará um dos grupos profissionais que mais irá crescer. Os
>   desenvolvedores estarão divididos entre 140 mil startups, 230 mil
>   empresas de desenvolvimento de sistemas e diversas outros segmentos de
>   empresas.

**Vantagens**

> Fornecedores - O mercado é relativamente maduro e existem inúmeros
>   fornecedores confiáveis para todos os tipos de necessidades. Esforço
>   de Desenvolvimento - Um desenvolvedor pode economizar semanas no que
>   tange à criação de um backend. Um BaaS é uma alternativa bastante boa
>   para acelerar o desenvolvimento de sistemas. Monetização - Dado que o
>   tempo para a criação de uma aplicação é bem menor, o MVP pode ser
>   lançado de forma muito rápida. Consequentemente, a geração de receita
>   se inicia mais cedo. Muito importante, em especial, para startups.
>   Escalabilidade - A quantidade de usuários pode ser escalada sem
>   interrupções ou perda de performance. Segurança - As empresas de BaaS
>   fornecem protocolos de segurança muito bons.

**Desvantagens**

> Controle - Os desenvolvedores apresentam menor controle sobre o código
>   fonte e o acesso ao backend é mais restrito. Vendor Lock In - O
>   usuário deve ser cauteloso e avaliar de forma muito criteriosa os
>   fornecedores. É uma decisão de longo prazo e deve ser dada preferência
>   a fornecedores que permitam a migração de dados ser houver
>   necessidade. Palavras Chave: BaaS ,API , Backend, Parse, Parse
>   Alternativa, Firebase, Parse Migração, Backend as a Service, Servidor,
>   Infraestrutura.

**Tecnologias que Envolvem o BaaS**

> O **BaaS** fornece um armazenamento em nuvens em uma base de dados
>   **NoSQL (MongoDB, DynamoDB, etc..)**, mas não é somente isso, na grande maioria temos **SDK’s** bem desenvolvidos com componentes
>   robustos como:
>
> **Notificações Push** - Em alguns servidores é possível ter uma análise detalhada dos push enviados. Ex: Quem Recebeu, Quem Abriu.
>
> **Integração com Redes Sociais** - É possível adicionar login com facebook em poucas linhas.
>
> **Serviços de armazenamento de arquivos -** Muitos usam S3 da amazon para otimizar este serviço
>
> **Geoqueries -** É possível montar querys de localização de forma rápida. Ex: Você precisa encontrar pessoas no raio de 1km.
>
> **ACL -** Controle de acesso feita a nível de usuário, perfil, collection (abstração de tabelas NoSQL).
>
> **Aplicativo Offline -** Para app’s mobile essa funcionalidade é essencial, ele salva os registros localmente e em alguns SDK’s a
>   sincronia é feita automaticamente assim que o app fique online.
>
> **Gestão de usuários -** Cadastro, recuperação de senha, login, envio de email. Tudo pronto.

Comment: Gostei da resposta, saberia responder a última pergunta (_"Quais as principais tecnologias por trás deles?"_)? Recomendo a leitura: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam atualizei acima, verifica se é isto que realmente quer, pois a pergunta está muito abrangente.

Comment: Essa pergunta é mais em relação as linguagens, por exemplo, SQL, NoSQL, JS (Node), PHP ...

Answer (score 11):

Vou dar uma resposta objetiva e outra subjetiva.

*Backend* as a Service é um conjunto de serviços, ou microsserviços, se preferir, que lhe dá "tudo" o que precisa para manter uma solução que interage com clientes diversos, em geral se fala muito em mobile e web, porém é qualquer coisa que use tecnologias web para se comunicar, de forma que o que você precisa desenvolver no *backend* seja mínimo, ou seja, você só foi o que é específico, não precisa se preocupar com o que praticamente toda aplicação tem que fazer, não se preocupa com a infraestrutura, nada que seja um problema geral e conhecido.

Podemos dizer que é um Serverless com uma atividade mais específica.

Bem grosso modo é como você ter um CMS prontinho para uso, onde você personaliza algumas coisas. Ele em si é um *framework*, mas com forma de usar um pouco diferente.

Em geral é fornecido como uma [API, igual é em um *framework*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/101), mas o último você tem o software em suas mãos e faz o que deseja com ele, incluindo coloca onde quiser e cuidar como quiser, já o BaaS você só tem que usar a API, tudo está pronto para uso.

Não tem nada de muito especial que não exista de outras formas, é uma nuvem com acesso ao banco de dados de forma já mais controlada, com facilidades de armazenamento do conteúdo, indexação, gerenciamento de usuário e interação comum com eles, de trocas e roteamento de mensagens, integrações, incluindo com redes sociais e outros softwares de massa, notificações, estatísticas de uso do seu serviço, controle de publicidade e monetização, serviços específicos como chat e outros meios colaborativos, regras de negócios, e vão sendo adicionadas funcionalidades que sejam comuns a vários tipos de aplicação.

É complicado fazer uma lista de fornecedores e listar o que é bom ou ruim de cada um. Vou citar apenas dois exemplos de gigantes: [Azure Mobile](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/solutions/mobile/) e [FireBase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebase).

Isso é uma forma legítima da indústria oferecer algo pronto que facilita para quem não é programador ou que tem dificuldade, ou ainda que precisa de algo rápido. Obviamente que é algo com um custo mais alto do que se você resolvesse fazer por conta própria e é menos flexível.  Mas pode sair mais barato se contar todo o trabalho para fazer algo específico, se contar que pode sair mal feito, ter falhas de segurança, e ter outras dificuldades. Claro que tudo pode dar errado, BaaS não é bala de prata, nada é.

Você tem que decidir se é o que melhor te atende, o que dará a melhor experiência para seus usuários, que estão dentro das expectativas financeiras de quem paga a conta.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado, mas poderia fazer uma comparação de quando eu posso usar um ou outro? No momento só conheço e uso o firebase mas gostaria de conhecer seus concorrentes. Talvez numa pergunta diferente?

Comment: sabe dizer quais as principais tecnologias usadas para criar essas APIs? Acredito que a principal seja o Node.js, devido sua escabilidade, mas não conheço muito bem a área

Answer (score -3):

Para complementar a excelente resposta de user109930, também diria que as edge functions são uma característica muito importante que pode integrar o estilo serverless.

E em relação às tecnologias de base de dados, não se limitam apenas a NoSQL, mas também são frequentemente utilizados sistemas SQL. [CASE](https://case.app) e [Pocketbase](https://pocketbase.io/) são exemplos de backends como serviço que utilizam SQLite, enquanto outros usam PostgreSQL ou MySQL.