# Posso chamar uma classe que faz apenas um cadastro de controller?

Tags: java, android, mvc, controller

Tenho uma classe de uma aplicação android que faz apenas o cadastro de usuário e a chamei de UsuarioController. A meu ver controller faz a comunicação entre view e model, mas como a classe só faz um cadastro, creio que ela poderia ser também um DAO. Ainda tenho uma certa dificuldade de entender o que fica em um controller e em um DAO

```
package com.app.eventos.controllers;
import com.app.eventos.dao.ConfiguracaoFirebase;
import com.app.eventos.dao.ConfiguracaoFirebaseAuth;
import com.app.eventos.model.Usuario;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class UsuarioController {
    private Usuario usuario;

    public UsuarioController() {}

    public void cadastrarUsuario(String nome, String email
    , String senha, String idUser) {
        usuario = new Usuario(nome, email, senha);

        ConfiguracaoFirebase.getDatabaseReference()
        .child("usuarios").child(idUser).setValue(usuario);
    }
}
```

Comment: Juliana, você poderia editar sua pergunta e, em vez de colar uma imagem, colocar a classe em formato texto? Com o tempo, se o link da imagem expirar, sua pergunta vai perder o sentido e dificultar para outros que tenham a mesma dúvida que a sua ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quantidade de operações que uma classe faz não define o que ela é ou o seu comportamento, uma classe que realiza o cadastro de 5 objetos diferentes não muda seu comportamento porque agora cadastra apenas 3

O controller, como o próprio nome diz, controla a aplicação, recebe as requisições/instruções que o usuário envia, interpreta e devolve o resultado, durante a interpretação ele pode interagir com outras classes, como model e o DAO

O DAO é uma classe que tem apenas uma tarefa, interagir com o banco, quando usado com o Firebase, não é muito útil (comparado a um banco de dados que não seja um [baas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/298361/)), já que a ação de escrita e leitura é apenas uma linha

No seu caso, seu controller também é um DAO, já que, aparentemente recebe os dados enviados do usuário, interage com o model e cadastra no banco

[O que é MVC(Model, View, Controller)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55486/o-que-%C3%A9-mvcmodel-view-controller)